# background-img not showing in a bootstrap card

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with my Bootstrap cards when it comes to showing background images.
I have a DIV with a fixed height within my card, to which I set an inline background image on an Razor page.

I know the path to the image is correct because it does show if I put the same path in an IMG.
Here are the site.css file and the Views/FoodItem/Index.cshtml

```css
.card-columns .card-img {
    height: 300px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-position: center; /* Center the image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
    background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
    opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img" style="background-image:url('~/images/StrawberryVanillaSoftCream2110111446.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Strawberry Vanilla Soft Cream</h5>
                <p class="card-text">¥800.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">
                    <a href="/FoodItem/Edit/13">Edit</a> |
                    <a href="/FoodItem/Details/13">Details</a> |
                    <a href="/FoodItem/Delete/13">Delete</a>
                </small>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing? The path to the image is definitely correct, and I can apply a background color to the .card-img DIV without problems, which allows me to see the my div is not collapsed and has the right size. The background image just doesn't show up.
Directory Structure is as follows:
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqUkr.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `~/` is directory for current user dir on _your_ computer. URL must be web accessible. If it's local file, there is even more restrictions - like it must be under same root folder. Check your Network and Console tabs, you should see CORS restriction error

Comment: Can you tell me your project directory structure?

Comment: show your directory structure.

Comment: Temporarily fixed with passing the https localhost url, but I assume it will have to change when (if) it gets deployed?